# Browser font-size of 40px is triggering mobile layout. Is this a bug?

Tags: css, accessibility, font-size

...Or is there a way do deal with this?

Basically, as the title says, when I change my browser font-size to 40px, the mobile site is triggered. I can't really think of a way to combat this, so I'm wondering how this could eventually be fixed?

Comment: Could you add some Information? What does your Code look like, which browser are you using etc. Like this we can just guess why this happens.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Just to add to what @Warden330 said, please read [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you get started here. At the moment there is not enough information in your question so we can help. At the very least a public URL in the comments of a site that exhibits this behaviour would be useful to help us explain.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not a bug, but a feature: For accessibility's sake, we want to avoid horizontal scrolling, layouts with ultra-narrow columns or text flowing out of it's containers. Hence, with a big zoom factor (or a big font size), a linear layout, aka "mobile site", is generally preferable.

(At this point I'm guessing the following is your issue, to be refined)

In Responsive Web Design, different layouts are achieved with so called breakpoints, that are [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), often based on [viewport-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/width).

Breakpoints can be based on pixels, but to render them more content-based, can be based on text size, in `rem`. A breakpoint at 30rem could be read like "use this layout if, at the current text size and current viewport size, a text of ~ 30 characters fits in a line".

You seem convinced that even at 40px text size your non-mobile layout still works well without horizontal scrolling and overflowing texts. Based on plenty of assumptions, your solution would probably be to extend your breakpoint to narrower viewports.

Assuming you are using mobile-first breakpoints, you would change the following in your CSS files:

```
-@media (min-width: 30rem)
+@media (min-width: 20rem)
```